# MySQL how to import different charsets in tsv file

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a tsv file containing 1.3M rows with different charsets like Latin, Russian, Chinese, etc.

this is my table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE `zip_test` (
    `country_code` VARCHAR(2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `postal_code` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `place_name` VARCHAR(180) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=160467
;
```

By running this from the command line, I managed to see Russian characters ok, but others still not shown correctly.

```
mysql -uUser -pPass --default-character-set=utf8 --local-infile database -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.tsv'  INTO TABLE table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

How can I solve this issue? What I'm doing wrong? I've never worked with anything different from Latin before.

Comment: What client are you using?  Can it display Chinese at all?  Is it using `UTF-8`?

Comment: @RickJames I was using Heidi, they show ok now. As I mentioned in my auto answer after changing to CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci; everything works just fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was doing a couple of things wrong.

This article clarifies thing a lot
https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

I have to run this to prepare my database

```
    # For each database:
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each table:
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# For each column:
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE column_name column_name VARCHAR(191) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
# (Don’t blindly copy-paste this! The exact statement depends on the column type, maximum length, and other properties. The above line is just an example for a `VARCHAR` column.)
```

And also my command line needs to be corrected to:

```
mysql -uUser -pPass --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --local-infile database -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.tsv'  INTO TABLE table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```